# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 or code 1) when call button action

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, icarousel

I am using the [iCarousel Library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) and am having some problems.

In the Controls Demo Example Project, a XIB file is used and the view is setup like:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (!view)
    {
        //load new item view instance from nib
        //control events are bound to view controller in nib file
        //note that it is only safe to use the reusingView if we return the same nib for each
        //item view, if different items have different contents, ignore the reusingView value
        view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }
    return view;
}
```

Because I am using Storyboards I create a View Controller and setup the view like this:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    NSString * viewControllerID = @"DuuinNewsItem";
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (!view)
    {
        DUDuuin *tDuuin = [_duuins objectAtIndex:index];
        DUNewsItemViewController * controller = (DUNewsItemViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
        controller.duuin =  tDuuin;
        view = controller.view;
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 314.0f, 415.0f)];

    }

    return view;
}
```

When I add an action to any button in the view I get the error:

[image]

I have tried a lot of things that are recommended in Stackoverflow, but I cannot find a solution:

I tried:

- Setting the outlet to Strong (someone says it's a problem because ARC)
- Deleting the sender in the action
- Adding the method in the View Controller that have the icarousel

****UPDATE****

Now i see other issue. When i define the Action in the DUNewsItemViewController and try it in the simulator, it says :

```
-[__NSCFType btnTest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1577c650
```

So, i adde the method in the .m file of the View Controller that have the iCarousel and the problem still the same:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)
```

Some info:

- I'm using ARC
- It's on Storyboards
- The number of views is dynamic

Comment: What is your outlet that you set to strong? An outlet for `iCarousel`,  `DUNewsItemViewController` or the `View`?

Comment: the outlet of the Button @Firo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue here is not with the view specifically but rather with your `DUNewsItemViewController` instance. You create your controller in the method you have provided and return the view. The view is being retained by `iCarousel`. Your `DUNewsItemViewController` on the other hand is not. There is nothing that is strongly pointing to it. Since there are no strong pointers to it, it is being deallocated. Your view is displaying correctly, with all of your buttons, because again, it is being retained outside of your `DUNewsItemViewController`. When a button is pressed it attempts to access its action method and fails because the controller no longer exists.

To fix this issue you need to create a strong pointer to your controller (not the button as you attempted before). I am not recommending a perfect strategy, rather one that works.

You could create a mutable array (as a property) and add the viewcontrollers into it (if there are more than one) as you create them. This way the controller that is `iCarousel`'s delegate/datasource holds a reference to it:

```
if (!view)
{
    DUDuuin *tDuuin = [_duuins objectAtIndex:index];
    DUNewsItemViewController * controller = (DUNewsItemViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
    // Add controller to array to hold a strong reference to it.
    [self.myMutableArray addObject:controller];
    //
    controller.duuin =  tDuuin;
    view = controller.view;
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 314.0f, 415.0f)];

}
```

Otherwise, if there is only one (or a few) you could create unique outlets:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) DUNewsItemViewController *firstVC;
```

and in your `carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView:view` method include a line `self.firstVC = controller`.

If something does not make sense let me know. Again, there are probably better implementations but this should work. The reason that the XIBs worked in the example is because they are just `UIViews` not `UIViewController` subclasses like you are using. Again, your view is working like it should (displaying, just like the example), but your controller is being deallocaed (not like the example, since there is no controller being used).

Comment: wow thanks, it make sense !, let me try it and i will tell you if it works! @Firo

Comment: It doesn't works bro, i declare a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *views;` inside te .m file, and i add the objects ok, but the problem is the same. **i update the question** @Firo

Comment: Don't add the views into the array. Add the ViewControllers. (I am assuming you just added the views since your array is called `views`

Comment: I added the ViewControllers into the array, i call the views in the carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView:view 'cause it returns a view, any ideas bro? @Firo

Comment: I updated my answer, see if this is how you are adding the controllers to the array.

Comment: it was my fault, i was saving only the view, no the controller (when i try it was the 4 A.M. in my country i was tired) so THANKS BRO !! a lot ! you save my day!

Comment: Yes, I completely understand! I think we have all been there before; glad it worked out!

Comment: Thanks Firo, you put me on the right track @FxckDead, to apply Firo's answer to another scenario, I have subclassed QLPreviewController and tried to use init it like i do my other view controllers, using [self.storyboard instantiateWith... etc]. This was an incorrect implementation, and simply [QLPreviewController alloc] init]; was appropriate. I believe it's own view is created and handled without my storyboard handling it. Works a charm now anyway. Thanks, good luck to you both!!